# Timemachine Sparsebundle from 2014 is missing partion map and file system

Tags: finder, backup, time-machine, sparsebundle

I need to get data off of an old sparsebundle file but when opened, it says eject or initialize. In finder it says it is 56 GB but once its mounted it shows the full size of the external (2 TB).

It is not showing a filesystem and have no idea how to fix.

**This is different from other questions because repairing from disk utility doesn't work or produce results.**

Here is where I am... these are two outputs, based on when they were mounted they show two different disks 4 and 11.

```
% hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck -stdinpass /Volumes/Samsung\ 1tb/problem.sparsebundle

% diskutil list /dev/disk4 
/dev/disk4 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   +2.0 TB     disk4
% diskutil info /dev/disk4
   Device Identifier:         disk4
   Device Node:               /dev/disk4
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk4
   Device / Media Name:       Disk Image

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       None
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  Disk Image
   SMART Status:              Not Supported

   Disk Size:                 2.0 TB (1998251409408 Bytes) (exactly 3902834784 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Removable
   Media Removal:             Software-Activated

   Solid State:               Info not available
   Virtual:                   Yes


    Last login: Wed Feb  7 16:22:56 on ttys002
% hdiutil attach -nomount -readwrite -noverify -noautofsck /Volumes/Samsung\ 1tb/problem.sparsebundle 
/dev/disk11                                             
% chmod -R 777 /Volumes/Samsung\ 1tb/problem.sparsebundle
% chflags -R nouchg /Volumes/Samsung\ 1tb/problem.sparsebundle
% hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -readwrite -noautofsck /Volumes/Samsung\ 1tb/problem.sparsebundle 
/dev/disk11                                             
% hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck -stdinpass -debug  /Volumes/Samsung\ 1tb/problem.sparsebundle 
Enter disk image passphrase:
2024-02-08 14:18:47.644 hdiutil[67172:7258498] DIHLDiskImageAttach: creating DIHelperProxy
2024-02-08 14:18:47.644 hdiutil[67172:7258498] with dictionary: {
    agent = hdiutil;
    "auto-fsck" = 0;
    debug = 1;
    "drive-options" = {length = 42, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d0080000 00000000 ... 00000000 00000009 };
    "image-options" = {length = 66, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d101025a 70617373 ... 00000000 0000001f };
    "main-url" = "file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/";
    "mount-attempted" = 0;
    "mount-required" = 0;
    operation = DIHelperAttach;
    quiet = 0;
    "skip-verify" = 1;
    verbose = 0;
}
2024-02-08 14:18:47.644 hdiutil[67172:7258498] [DIHelperProxy alloc]
2024-02-08 14:18:47.644 hdiutil[67172:7258498] [DIHelperProxy alloc] returning self 0x600002630000, retainCount 1
2024-02-08 14:18:47.644 hdiutil[67172:7258498] DIHLDiskImageAttach: running DIHelperProxy
2024-02-08 14:18:47.644 hdiutil[67172:7258498] [DIHelperProxy performOperationReturning] entry
2024-02-08 14:18:47.644 hdiutil[67172:7258498] [DIHelperProxy performOperationReturning] detaching thread
2024-02-08 14:18:47.644 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] entry
2024-02-08 14:18:47.644 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] setting up server
2024-02-08 14:18:47.644 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy threadSetupServer] entry
2024-02-08 14:18:47.644 hdiutil[67172:7258557] XPC: creating helperconnection connection
2024-02-08 14:18:47.646 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy threadSetupServer] exiting
2024-02-08 14:18:47.646 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy threadLaunchToolAuthenticated] entry (spawn version)
2024-02-08 14:18:47.646 hdiutil[67172:7258557] launching helper tool at "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/Resources/diskimages-helper".
2024-02-08 14:18:47.647 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy threadLaunchToolAuthenticated] exiting (spawn version)
2024-02-08 14:18:47.647 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] calling waitForHelperDone
2024-02-08 14:18:47.654 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy connectToFramework] entry, helper
2024-02-08 14:18:47.654 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy sendOperationToHelper] entry
2024-02-08 14:18:47.654 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy sendOperationToHelper] starting operation with helper
2024-02-08 14:18:47.655 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy sendOperationToHelper] exit
2024-02-08 14:18:47.655 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy connectToFramework] exit
2024-02-08 14:18:47.661 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] entry
status proc called: initialize
Initializing…
myStatusProc: returning 0 
2024-02-08 14:18:47.662 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit
2024-02-08 14:18:47.663 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] updateImageAndDriveDictionaries: before update _imageOptions: {
    "enable-keychain" = 1;
}
2024-02-08 14:18:47.663 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] _driveOptions: {
    "auto-fsck" = 0;
    autodiskmount = 0;
    "unmount-timeout" = 0;
}
2024-02-08 14:18:47.663 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] DIHelperAttach: performOperation: initializing framework
2024-02-08 14:18:47.663 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] {
    agent = hdiutil;
    "allow-tty-prompt" = 1;
    "auto-fsck" = 0;
    "auto-fsck-failure-override-type" = callback;
    "auto-open-ro-root" = 0;
    "auto-open-rw-root" = 0;
    "auto-stretch" = 0;
    "bundlebs-checkpointing" = 0;
    "bundlebs-localcloseonflush" = 0;
    "bundlebs-localcloseonidle" = 0;
    "bundlebs-localcloseonsleep" = 0;
    "bundlebs-localfdcount" = 6;
    "bundlebs-remotecloseonflush" = 0;
    "bundlebs-remotecloseonidle" = 0;
    "bundlebs-remotecloseonsleep" = 0;
    "bundlebs-remotefdcount" = 3;
    "burn-no-underrun-protection" = 0;
    "burn-synthesize-content" = 1;
    "bzip2-level" = 0;
    "callback-with-sla" = 1;
    debug = 1;
    "disable-encrypted-images" = 0;
    "disable-kernel-mounting" = 1;
    "disable-owners" = 0;
    "drive-options" = {length = 42, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d0080000 00000000 ... 00000000 00000009 };
    "enable-owners" = 0;
    "hfsplus-stretch-parameters" =     {
        "hfsplus-stretch-allocation-block-size" = 4096;
        "hfsplus-stretch-allocation-file-size" = 8388608;
        "hfsplus-stretch-threshold" = 524288;
    };
    "idle-timeout" = 15;
    "ifd-format" = UDZO;
    "ifd-segment-size" = 0;
    "iff-format" = UDZO;
    "iff-fs" = "HFS+";
    "iff-layout" = GPTSPUD;
    "iff-source-owners" = auto;
    "iff-spotlight-indexing" = 0;
    "iff-temp-sparse-band-size" = 20480;
    "iff-temp-use-rw-if-possible" = 1;
    "iff-usehelper" = 1;
    "ignore-bad-checksums" = 0;
    "image-options" = {length = 66, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d101025a 70617373 ... 00000000 0000001f };
    "main-url" = "file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/";
    "mount-attempted" = 0;
    "mount-point" = "/Volumes/";
    "mount-private" = 0;
    "mount-required" = 0;
    "mount-type" = in;
    "nbi-spotlight-indexing" = 0;
    operation = DIHelperAttach;
    "pthread-reader-cap" = 4;
    quiet = 0;
    "skip-auto-fsck-for-system-images" = 1;
    "skip-previously-verified" = 1;
    "skip-sla" = 0;
    "skip-verify" = 1;
    "skip-verify-locked" = 0;
    "skip-verify-remote" = 1;
    "sparsebundle-compactonidle" = 0;
    "suppress-uiagent" = 1;
    "unmount-timeout" = 0;
    "use-keychain" = 1;
    verbose = 0;
    "zlib-level" = 1;
}
DILoadDriver: checking for disk image driver
DILoadDriver: DI_kextExists() returned 0x00000000 (0)
DIIsInitialized: returning NO
2024-02-08 14:18:47.665 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] -checkForPreviouslyAttachedImage: entry
2024-02-08 14:18:47.665 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] imageURL file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/
2024-02-08 14:18:47.665 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] shadowURL (null)
2024-02-08 14:18:47.665 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] sectionStart (null) sectionLength (null)
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: entry with
file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/
skip-permissions-check: true
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: entry
file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/
skip-permissions-check: true
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 0 CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe directory, not a valid image file.
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 1 CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe: got bundle
CFBundle 0x600000910000 </Volumes/Samsung 1tb/problem.sparsebundle> (not loaded)
band-size: 8388608
bundle-backingstore-version: 1
diskimage-bundle-type: com.apple.diskimage.sparsebundle
size: 1998251409408
CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion: 6.0
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe score 1000 for file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score     1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 2 CRAMBackingStore
CRAMBackingStore::probe: scheme "file": not ram: or ramdisk: scheme.
CRAMBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 3 CDevBackingStore
CDevBackingStore::newProbe: not /dev/disk or /dev/rdisk (/Volumes/Samsung 1tb/problem.sparsebundle).
CDevBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 4 CCURLBackingStore
CCURLBackingStore::probe: scheme is: file
CCURLBackingStore::probe: not recognized URL scheme.
CCURLBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 5 CVectoredBackingStore
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe not "vectored" scheme.
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: selecting CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: perm is 0
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: entry with
file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/token
bs-no-follow: true
skip-permissions-check: true
use-filename-for-prompt: problem.sparsebundle
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: entry
file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/token
bs-no-follow: true
skip-permissions-check: true
use-filename-for-prompt: problem.sparsebundle
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 0 CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe score 100 for file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 1 CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 2 CRAMBackingStore
CRAMBackingStore::probe: scheme "file": not ram: or ramdisk: scheme.
CRAMBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 3 CDevBackingStore
CDevBackingStore::newProbe: not /dev/disk or /dev/rdisk (/Volumes/Samsung 1tb/problem.sparsebundle/token).
CDevBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 4 CCURLBackingStore
CCURLBackingStore::probe: scheme is: file
CCURLBackingStore::probe: not recognized URL scheme.
CCURLBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 5 CVectoredBackingStore
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe not "vectored" scheme.
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: selecting CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::setNoFollow: setting _noFollow to 1
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: instantiator returned 0
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: returning 0
CBundleBackingStore::setURL entry
CBundleBackingStore::setURL CFURLStat passed
CBundleBackingStore::setURL fPath is /Volumes/Samsung 1tb/problem.sparsebundle
CBundleBackingStore::isRemote: returning false
CBundleBackingStore::setURL got unique identifier
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: setURL returned 0
CBundleBackingStore::setSecurityToken entry
CBundleBackingStore::setSecurityToken proxy encoding not supported
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: setSecurityToken returned 0
copyInfoPlist: fcntl(F_OPENFROM, Info.plist) passed
copyInfoPlist: total read 500 bytes
band-size: 8388608
bundle-backingstore-version: 1
diskimage-bundle-type: com.apple.diskimage.sparsebundle
size: 1998251409408
CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion: 6.0
CBundleBackingStore::processBundle: getting kDIBackingStoreSizeKey
CBundleBackingStore::processBundle: dfLength 1998251409408
CBundleBackingStore::processBundle: getting kDIBackingStoreBandSizeKey
CBundleBackingStore::processBundle: _bytesPerBand 8388608
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: processBundle returned 0
CBundleBackingStore::isRemote: returning false
CBundleBackingStore::processOptions: _maxOpenBands is 6 entries
CBundleBackingStore::processOptions: kMaxAsyncCloses is 16 
CBundleBackingStore::processOptions: _bandTableCloseOnSleep is no
CBundleBackingStore::processOptions: _bandTableCloseOnIdle is no
CBundleBackingStore::processOptions: _bandTableCloseOnFlush is no
CBundleBackingStore::processOptions: _bandTable initialized
CBundleBackingStore::setPermission entry inPerm = 0
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: setPermission returned 0
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: returning 0
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: instantiator returned 0
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: returning 0
2024-02-08 14:18:47.667 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] -checkForPreviouslyAttachedImage: resolving file:///Volumes/Samsung%201tb/problem.sparsebundle/ returned 0
2024-02-08 14:18:47.667 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] -checkForPreviouslyAttachedImage: imageUID (
    "d16777257:i12859421"
) shadowUID (null)
***** testing:
0: d16777257:i12859421
(null)
(null)
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] DIHelperAttach: performOperation: image previously attached as
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] {
    "system-entities" =     (
                {
            "content-hint" = "";
            "dev-entry" = "/dev/disk11";
        }
    );
}
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] -[DIHelperHDID initWithDiskImage:]
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] enableCallbacks() entry
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] enableCallbacks() call backs now enabled
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] DIHelperAttach: performOperation: attaching disk image
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] performAttach: entry
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] [DIHelperOperator frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] calling home {
    "status-stage" = attach;
}
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] entry
status proc called: attach
Attaching…
myStatusProc: returning 0 
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] [DIHelperOperator frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit 0
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] _needToAutoFsck: auto-fsck=NO detected
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] _needToAutoFsck: returning NO
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] setMountFlags: 0x0
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] performAttach: calling remountReturningDictionary
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] -remountReturningDictionary:
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] _buildReturnDictionary:
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] _dictionaryFromDisk: adding (disk11): {
    "dev-entry" = "/dev/disk11";
    "potentially-mountable" = 0;
}
2024-02-08 14:18:47.668 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] -remountReturningDictionary: _buildReturnDictionary returned 0
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] -remountReturningDictionary: kicked off hdiejectd
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] DIHelperAttach: performOperation: post-processing disk image
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] [DIHelperOperator frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] calling home {
    "status-stage" = "post-process";
}
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] entry
status proc called: post-process
Finishing…
myStatusProc: returning 0 
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] [DIHelperOperator frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit 0
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] postProcessing: devEntry: /dev/disk11 mountPoint: (null)
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] performPostProcessing: returning 0.
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] [DIHelperOperator frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] calling home {
    "status-stage" = cleanup;
}
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] entry
status proc called: cleanup
Finishing…
myStatusProc: returning 0 
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] [DIHelperOperator frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit 0
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] -[DIHelperHDIDDA dealloc:]
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] disableCallbacks() entry
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] disableCallbacks() call backs now disabled
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] -[DIHelperHDID dealloc:]
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] DIHelperAttach performOperation: returning 0
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258563] -decrementBackgroundThreadCount: _backgroundThreadCount is now 0.
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258561] DIHelper _report_results: reporting {
    payload =     {
        "system-entities" =         (
                        {
                "dev-entry" = "/dev/disk11";
                "potentially-mountable" = 0;
            }
        );
    };
    "result-code" = 0;
}
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258501] reportResultsToFramework: proxy has finished operation
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258501] reportResultsToFramework: results are: {
    payload =     {
        "system-entities" =         (
                        {
                "dev-entry" = "/dev/disk11";
                "potentially-mountable" = 0;
            }
        );
    };
    "result-code" = 0;
}
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258501] reportResultsToFramework: _threadResultsError is 0
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258501] reportResultsToFramework: disconnecting from helper.
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy disconnectFromHelper] entry
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258501] disconnectFromHelper: terminating proxy
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258557] -[DIHelperProxy(Thread) waitForHelperDone]: done waiting. _helperDone=1
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy waitForHelperDone] releasing connection
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] after waitForHelperDone
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258501] disconnectFromHelper: terminated proxy
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] waiting for task to terminate to avoid zombies
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 hdiutil[67172:7258501] [DIHelperProxy disconnectFromHelper] exit
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258562] DIHelper: terminateHelper: entry.
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258562] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] entry
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258562] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] releasing connection
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258562] -DIHelperAgentMaster terminateUIAgentConnection.
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258562] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] marking _frameworkDisconnected
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258562] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] preparing to act like a daemon.
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258562] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] exiting
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258561] -setCanTerminate: main thread can exit
2024-02-08 14:18:47.669 diskimages-helper[67174:7258561] helper: child_after_exec returning 0
2024-02-08 14:18:47.670 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] helper exited
2024-02-08 14:18:47.670 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] exiting
2024-02-08 14:18:47.670 hdiutil[67172:7258498] [DIHelperProxy performOperationReturning] returning 0
2024-02-08 14:18:47.670 hdiutil[67172:7258498] DIHLDiskImageAttach: DIHelperProxy returned 0
DIHLDiskImageAttach() returned 0
2024-02-08 14:18:47.670 hdiutil[67172:7258557] [DIHelperProxy dealloc]
system-entities:
    0:
        dev-entry: /dev/disk11
        potentially-mountable: false
/dev/disk11
```

Comment: The answer to the original question (and the blog post linked there) doesn‘t use Disk Utility. Can you describe the steps you took to solve the issue and how they failed?